# Git on Windows fails to push local branch

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, push

I installed Git Client in Windows and have created a initial branch locally. Currently I am trying to push the first version to the Git Server. But it does not get through successfully. I received the following error message:

Pushing to git@(my_git_server).git
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Here is what I did for the setup:

1. Generate public and private key:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "(my email id)"

1. Copy the public key to Git server
2. Use KeyGen.exe to convert open ssh key to Putty private key
3. Load the private key with pageant.
4. Try to push the local branch to the server. (Failed)
5. I tried to SSH to the git Server and received the following error message:

server unexpected closed network connection.

Please kindly help me out.

Comment: Can you share the exact command used for pushing to your git server???

Comment: Check your remote URL. Enter `git remote -v`

Comment: Hi thanks guys for replying. Actually I just use Git GUI to push the branch instead of running any cmd

Comment: I will try to install TortoisGit and see if it works. Thanks to both of you